# Usar $_SESSION[ ] en vez de $_GET[ ] para pasar parámetros

Tags: php, session, get, parametros

Resulta que estoy creando con un grupo un proyecto el cual es una plataforma sencilla para reservar citas, donde los usuarios tienen su propia cuenta. El problemas es que hemos estado usando muy seguido el método de envío $_GET[] para pasar datos entre distintos archivos y según hemos investigado es una mala practica.

**Aquí la pregunta es ¿podemos usar nuevas variables de sesión $_SESSION[] para reemplazar el uso de $_GET[] y hacer menos vulnerable nuestro proyecto?**

Muchas gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: ```$_SESSION[]``` se utiliza para guardar datos de sesión y es mucho mejor que *GET* ya que este se utiliza más en formulario o cosas así, más no para pasar datos para pasar datos *del usuario*

Comment: Mucha gente incomprende GET. No es que sea inseguro ya que su finalidad NO ES enviar datos sensibles, si no agregar funcionalidad. Ejemplos, trazabilidad: `url?medium=facebook&campaign=534`; url temporal para recuperar contraseña: `url_recovery?uid=354&token=cadena_larguisima`. No importa que un ocioso cambie los datos, simplemente el servidor ya no los reconocerá. En backend, sirve para pasar datos entre sistemas: `hdd_monitor.php?vol_root=25.32&vol_oracle=241.32`

Comment: Sería de utilidad mas informacion acerca de "hemos estado usando muy seguido el método de envío $_GET[] para pasar datos entre distintos archivos"... que tipo de archivos, que tipo de información están pasando?

Comment: Pues básicamente datos como cedulas de los usuarios, nombres y correos